# RSS take too long to load in android

Tags: android, xml, rss, xml-parsing

I am using AsyncTask to get data from RSS feed and DOM parser and ArrayAdapter.

I noticed that the RSS feed is taking too long to load and show data on screen, at first I thought because the number of articles is big but when I limited the for loop to read only 3 articles it remained taking too long to show the articles!!

below is the full code I am using to parse the data and the main activity

Main activity code:

```
public class NewsMainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ListView listview;
    List<NewsBean> arrayList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initComponents();

        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            new MyRssReadTask()
                    .execute("feed_URL");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    private void initComponents() {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    class MyRssReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog waitingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            waitingDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsMainActivity.this);
            waitingDialog.setMessage("Loading articles, Please wait...");
            waitingDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            arrayList = new NewsParser().getData(urls[0]);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            waitingDialog.dismiss();
            setDataToListView();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    protected void setDataToListView() {
        if (null != arrayList && arrayList.size() != 0) {
            NewsRowAdapter objNewsRowAdapter = new NewsRowAdapter(
                    NewsMainActivity.this, R.layout.row, arrayList);

            listview.setAdapter(objNewsRowAdapter);
        } else {
            showToast("There was an error to get data, please try again later.");
        }

    }

    void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(NewsMainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        final NewsBean objBean = (NewsBean) arrayList.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(NewsMainActivity.this,
                NewsDetail.class);

        intent.putExtra("title", objBean.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("description", objBean.getDescription());
        //intent.putExtra("pubdate", objBean.getPubDate());
        //intent.putExtra("creator", objBean.getCreator());
        intent.putExtra("link", objBean.getLink());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

News Parser

```
public class NewsParser {


    private List<NewsBean> arrayListPasre;

    public List<NewsBean> getData(String _url) {
        try {

            arrayListPasre = new ArrayList<NewsBean>();
            URL url = new URL(_url);
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

            System.out.println("Connection is : " + con);

            System.out.println("Connection InputStream is : "
                    + con.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Reader us now : " + reader);

            String inputLine;
            String fullStr = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                fullStr = fullStr.concat(inputLine + "\n");

            InputStream istream = url.openStream();

            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();

            System.out.println("Builder : " + builder);

            Document doc = builder.parse(istream);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            System.out.println("nlist " + nList);

            for (int temp = 0; temp < 3; temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    NewsBean objBean = new NewsBean();

                    objBean.setTitle(getTagValue("title", eElement));
                    objBean.setDescription(getTagValue("description", eElement));
                    objBean.setLink(getTagValue("link", eElement));
                    arrayListPasre.add(objBean);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayListPasre;
    }

    private String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();

        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

        return nValue.getNodeValue();

    }
}
```

any suggestions i would be thankful!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You do no need to parse whole rss at once time. You can do this partially. For example parse document and get rss items count and then call you async task for 3 or 5 or 10 items only. In onPostExecute() add results to your adapter and call notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: where is a biggest delay? This Document doc = builder.parse(istream); ?

Comment: not quite sure, but yes it should be here when it parse the feed file and then normalize its elements

Comment: try to measure delays with System.currenttimemills and recognize biggest delay. If delay at this place try to use sax parser. You will can to do something while parsing is going for example create Otherwise  you need to do smth like this https://github.com/gobozov/LepraDroid/blob/master/LepraDroid/src/com/home/lepradroid/tasks/GetBlogsTask.java take a look to do - while loop